# How to upload image and status to twitter using twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, twitpic

I want to upload an image as well as status through my android application.

So far I have tried many examples, but none of them helped. (I already have the CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,TWITPIC_API_KEY and I'm able to post the status from my application,I only need the code for uploading an image).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ImageUpload class in twitter4j. The below code describes a typical scenario for image upload with text.

```
    AccessToken accessToken = twitterSession.getAccessToken();
    ConfigurationBuilder conf = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    conf.setOAuthConsumerKey(twitter_consumer_key);
    conf.setOAuthConsumerSecret(twitter_secret_key);
    conf.setUseSSL(true);
    conf.setHttpReadTimeout(2400000);
    conf.setHttpStreamingReadTimeout(2400000);
    conf.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken.getToken());
    conf.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessToken.getTokenSecret());
    conf.setMediaProviderAPIKey(twitpic_api_key);
    Configuration configuration = conf.build();
    OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(configuration);
    ImageUpload uploader = new ImageUploadFactory(configuration)
    .getInstance(auth);

    File photo=new File("abc/myimage.png");
    String status="Checkout my new image";

    uploader.upload(photo,status);
```

Comment: conf.setUseSSL(true); is not recoggnizing!!Do i need to add any libraby(other that twitter4j..)

Comment: Which version of twitter4j are you using

Answer (score 0):

At my time, the following sample is precious

https://github.com/learnNcode/DemoTwitterImagePost